# Storm-Crawler and Apache Strom 2.x.x

Tags: web-crawler, apache-storm, stormcrawler

Is Storm-Crawler planned to support Apache-Storm 2.x.x? I've already work on system which use Storm-Crawler but I must update Apache Storm version to 2.1.0

Answer (score 1):

See the [2.x branch](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/tree/2.x) and the recent [2.0 release](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/releases/tag/2.0) which is based on Apache Storm 2.1.0.